# How to get the transaction public key and outputs from get_transactions?

Tags: daemon, rpc

I'm trying to get the outputs and tx public key according to [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11653/can-i-process-incoming-transfers-from-the-daemon-rpc/11654#11654).

I know that the transaction public key must be in the "extra" section. 
When I ran the [get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) command, I got this response 
(displaying only the "extra" part):

```
"extra": [ 1, 108, 109, 63, 78, 182, 147, 31, 13, 63, 251, 116, 213, 150, 92, 35, 157, 53, 55, 182, 160, 24, 206, 159, 131, 96, 160, 20, 147, 162, 61, 159, 75, 2, 9, 1, 214, 209, 43, 119, 113, 218, 18, 237  ]
```

This is how documentation defines "extra":

> extra - Usually called the "payment ID" but can be used to include any random 32 bytes.

According to the [pseudo-code mentioned above](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11653/can-i-process-incoming-transfers-from-the-daemon-rpc/11654#11654), what parts of the response given by [get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) do I need to process the incoming transfer?

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8306/how-to-parse-transaction-extra-field-to-extract-pubkey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the transaction public key and outputs from get_transactions?

Parse the field named `extra` to get the public key. The 32 bytes after the byte 0x01 is the tx public key.

The output keys are in `txs[].as_json.vout[].target[].key` if you used the parameter `decode_as_json:true`.